# comparison with a key from django session

Tags: django

i setup a session key in django and tried to retrieve and compare with a string of the same elements, i have checked the type and they are all str but it cant return true

```
otp = str(request.session["otp"])
print(otp,type(otp))
user_otp = str(request.POST.get("otp"))
print(user_otp,"user_otp",type(user_otp))
if user_otp == request.session["otp"]:
    return HttpResponse("u enter")
```

this is the log from the server after doing the print

```
B3me <class 'str'>
B3me  user_otp <class 'str'>
```

this shows they match but it doesnt return the HttpResponse

Comment: change your if statement to `if user_otp == otp:`, check you have type casted your session variable to `str`.

Comment: Are you sure `user_otp` doesn't have a space at the end?

Comment: i just checked to find the length and i realised that it has an extra space, thanks